# Translate my website content

Tags: php, html, translation

Guys I know that this question asked before but its not the same.

I have a website that I want to translate its content.

**What I came up with:**

1-gettext //its not good for me

2-google api //google translate is very bad and also google add its name in my wbesite

3-make another files with different language.

I prefer the last one because I only want my website to be English and Arabic.

Any more solutions? and what disadvantages of making the third solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam Essam,
What companies do nowadays is use something called i18n (internationalization) I believe you should check out this website: https://lingohub.com/blog/2013/06/php-internationalization-i18n-mechanisms-tutorial/ It also tells why the third method you're mentioning is bad. Hope it helps.

Comment: Salam Zatara thanks a lot and it really helped

Comment: I will but I have to wait more 4 min because of stackoverflow :D

Comment: My service www.sitetran.com enables you to translate the content on your site without any engineering. Good luck.